# How can I add images to a belong_to dropdown in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a class that belongs_to :primary_image, :class_name => 'Image'. In RailsAdmin this is rendered as a dropdown widget that shows me all images in the database. However, they all are "Image #" where # is their ID. In order for an admin to intelligently select an image, I'd like them to see thumbnails of the images instead. Is there a way to get the information that is added to the dropdown to be image tags with their source being a url from the Image instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `object_label` to set the column/function you wish to use as a display name for all instances.

```
config.model Image do
  object_label :url
end
```

---

I'm not sure you should use HTML there, but it would look like:

```
config.model Image do
  object_label :image_tag
end

# in image.rb
def image_tag
  %{<img src="#{self.url}">}.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is different in the gem version of RailsAdmin but I wasn't able to use object_label. I was able to use object_label_method :admin_label though.

Also in my admin_label method, it only works if I DO NOT put html_safe after the string. Either way it is working more or less. When the image is selected you see the HTML in the selection box but I don't think that'll be a problem for the client.